# replacing <p> elements with an image using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am having difficulty replacing a string (URL) with an image using jquery.  I want function to run on page load and replace a text string with an image. I need it to work on many different "strings" contained in `<event-description> <p>http://example.com/pageone.html </p> </event-description>on the page.` This is what I have:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

       $('.event-description p').each(function () {

       string = $(this).text('http://example.com/pageone.html');
       $(this).html('<img width="75" src="https://example.com/images/logo-one.jpg" alt="' + string + '" />');

       string = $(this).text('http://example.com/pagetwo.html');
       $(this).html('<img width="75" src="https://example.com/images/logo-two.jpg" alt="' + string + '" />');

    });



});
```

Any Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi @studionigh. Welcome to stackoverflow.  Can you please include your HTML content so we know what are you looking for?  I don't think there is an html tag called `<event-description>`  to my knowledge. So selector might be wrong.

Comment: `<div class="event-description"> 
     <p>http://example.com/pageone.html </p> 
</div>
<div class="event-description"> 
     <p>http://example.com/pagetwo.html </p> 
</div>`
There are multiple <div> called event-description, each with a different text string that needs to be replaced with a corresponding image.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a [condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) to compare the text of each `p`.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

  $('.event-description p').each(function () {
    
    var string = $(this).text();
    
    if($(this).text() == 'http://example.com/pageone.html'){
      $(this).html('<img width="75" src="https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1" alt="' + string + '" />');
    }

    if($(this).text() == 'http://example.com/pagetwo.html'){
    $(this).html('<img width="75" src="https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2" alt="' + string + '" />');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="event-description">
  <p>http://example.com/pageone.html</p>
  <p>http://example.com/pagetwo.html</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going. **Just keep in mind since I am using the same image in the loop, the image will be same for all the `<p>` element**. You can have an object mapping pointing to the exact image you need in there to make it dynamic or use `data` attribute which is recommended.

See below:
`<p data-imgurl='logo-one'>`, `data-imgurl` is image(logo) name here

**Note: This adds image inside the `<p>` tag you have. If you want remove `<p>` use   $(this).parent().html(...)**

```js
$(function(){ //shorhand for document.ready function (same as yours)
    $('.event-description p').each(function () {
           var $this = $(this);
       
           //take the current string present in `<p>` tag
           var currentString = $this.text(); 
           //get data attribute to get the image name
           var imgUrl = $this.data('imgurl');
           
           $(this).html('<img width="75" src="https://example.com/images/'+imgUrl+'.jpg" alt="' + currentString + '" />');
           //replace with image tag with alt attribute as previous string
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event-description">
  <p data-imgurl='logo-one'>http://example.com/pageone.html</p>
</div>

<div class="event-description">
  <p data-imgurl='logo-two'>http://example.com/pagetwo.html</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.replaceWith( function )](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/#replaceWith-function)

```js
$('.event-description p').replaceWith(function(idx, txt) {
  return $('<img/>', {width: "75", src: txt.trim(), alt: txt.trim()});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="event-description"><p>http://example.com/pageone.html </p></div>
<div class="event-description"><p>http://example.com/pagetwo.html </p></div>
```